# Error when loading or migrating database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I try to use rake db:schema:load or rake db:migrate, I get keep getting the following error:

```
The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2.
Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
no such file to load — mysql
```

I already have the mysql gem installed which is version 2.8.1. Am I missing something?

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: db_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password
  encoding: utf8
  socket: /Applications/rubystack/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: what driver are you using in your database.yml? that's probably the problem

Comment: Also, you might want to try "mysql2" instead of just "mysql". It solved this very specific problem for me many times!

Comment: @corroded - I am using the mysql driver. @Pierre I don't have mysql2 installed, but I will install it and see if it works.

Comment: can you post your database.yml?

Comment: @corroded - I posted the database.yml

Comment: I noticed it seems you're using Rails 2.2. If possible, you should consider migrating to at least the latest 2.3, as 2.2 no longer receives security updates.

Comment: you can try this then: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?116,240223,240229#msg-240229

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - No, I am using Rails 2.3.5 (rails -v)

Comment: @corroded - Unfortunately, its still giving me the same error

Comment: maybe you could try uninstalling all your mysql gems and then reinstalling it again using the method in the link?

Comment: @amye in that case you should still upgrade to 2.3.11, lots of security and bug fixes.

Comment: It sounds like rails may not be running the expected ruby.  Fire up irb from your shell and type `$:` to see your library path.  Run the same thing from your rails console...any notable differences?  Also, do you have the mysql gem in your environment.rb?

Comment: @amye Which OS you are using, is it Windows? After googling I found find that the bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. and thats the reason of being rails 2.2.x to be incompatible with mysql 5.x client. here is a solution. please follow the following steps to fix it:
1.  download older MySQL client library, for example one from 
InstantRails: 
http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/libmySQL.dll

2.  copy the downloaded file to C:\Ruby\bin (or wherever you installed 
Ruby)

3. restart MySQL server

Comment: Sorry for breaking the continuity it's cause of limited comment chars, now back to the question if you are working on linux system then try these commands in sequence: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client` 
`sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev`  `sudo gem install mysql` 
`sudo gem install mysql2` 
`sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev` I hope that will make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing mysql2 gem

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

If you are on Rails 3, add

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

to your Gemfile & run

```
bundle install
```

And change the adapter to mysql2 in your database.yml. I solved many problems with this, might solve yours too.